# How to bufferise the response from the action?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, httpresponse

How can I send some part of the web response without waiting the all rendering process finish?
I prefer do that in an Action.

I used to use `Response.Buffer = false;` in .net 2.0 but now with MVC 3 I don't know how to do that.

Comment: `Response.Buffer = true;` does the opposite of what you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can potentially use an Action Filter to set the Buffer property.

```
public class BufferActionFilter: ActionFilterAttribute
{
          public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
          {
               filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Buffer = true;       
          }
}
```

PS: I have not checked if this works though.